# PGFplots - Automatic choice of a cycle list according to the number of curves

Tags: pgfplots, color, plot

Is it possible for PGFplots to choose (automatically) such or such `cycle list` according to the number of curves to display ?

To illustrate, and using the `colobrewer` library, PGFplots could be configured to choose (automatically) the style `BuGn-3` if there are 3 or less curves to display, `BuGn-4` if there are 4 curves to display, `BuGn-5` if there are 5, etc.
Of course, this could work with any `cycle list`.

Here is a non-working MWE :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\newcounter{colorCycleCounter}
\preto\addplot{\stepcounter{colorCycleCounter}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{axis}{\setcounter{colorCycleCounter}{0}}

\newcommand{\colorCycle}{%
    \IfEqCase*{\value{colorCycleCounter}}{%
        {1} {cycle list name=BuGn-3}%
        {2} {cycle list name=BuGn-3}%
        {3} {cycle list name=BuGn-3}%
        {4} {cycle list name=BuGn-4}%
        {5} {cycle list name=BuGn-5}%
        {6} {cycle list name=BuGn-6}%
        {7} {cycle list name=BuGn-7}%
        {8} {cycle list name=BuGn-8}%
        {9} {cycle list name=BuGn-9}%
    }[]%
}%

\pgfplotsset{
cycle list/BuGn-3,
cycle list/BuGn-4,
cycle list/BuGn-5,
cycle list/BuGn-6,
cycle list/BuGn-7,
cycle list/BuGn-8,
cycle list/BuGn-9,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[\colorCycle]%"cycle list name=BuGn-3"
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[\colorCycle]%"cycle list name=BuGn-3"
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[\colorCycle]%"cycle list name=BuGn-5"
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(3,0)(4,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(4,0)(5,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is for example the expected result (by manually specifying the desired `cycle list`) for 4 graphs of 2, 3, 5 and 9 curves which will use the `cycle list` :

- `cycle list/BuGn-3` for the first two graphs,
- `cycle list/BuGn-5` for the third,
- `cycle list/BuGn-9` for the last one.

[image]

Comment: See if I understand your problem: You want in the first figure  all 3 lines to be colored with 1 color and second figure  all 3 lines to be colored with 1 color and last figure  all 5 lines to be colored with 5 colors: 3 color like before and 2 new color?

Comment: @C.F.G Not exactly, the goal is to create a command allowing PGFplots to choose automatically (default choice for each new graph) a `cycle list` according to the number of curves to display. If there is 1 curve to be displayed, use `cycle list` A, if there are 2 curves, use `cycle list` B, if there are 3, use `cycle list` C and so on. In the example I've taken, the `cycle lists` are all of the type `list/BuGn-` _n_, but I could also have used user-defined `cycle lists`.

Comment: Of course, we could do all this manually using the command `cycle list name=`, but automating this task would make things easier. In addition, we can easily forget to update our `cycle list` choice when adding a curve to the graph, and use `cycle list/BuGn-3` when we have 4 curves for example.

Comment: If the above output (image in your post) is not your desired you can set pgf color before each `tikzpicture` i.e.  using `\pgfplotsset{`

Comment: For example you can add `\pgfplotsset{` 4 times before each plot.

Comment: "Here is for example the expected result " : How did you produced that figures?

Comment: @C.F.G I manually specified the desired `cycle list` via the optional `cycle list name=` command in each graphic. Yes, as I said, wecan manually select the desired `cycle list`, but the whole point of Latex is to be able to take maximum advantage of automation. One can quickly forget to use `\pgfplotsset` before a graph and thus have a `cyle list` not suited to the number of curves in the graph.

Comment: Sorry that I am asking again. Please clarify why you have defined new command WHILE the `\pgfplotsset{
 cycle list/BuGn-3,
 cycle list/BuGn-4,
 cycle list/BuGn-5,
 cycle list/BuGn-6,
 cycle list/BuGn-7,
 cycle list/BuGn-8,
 cycle list/BuGn-9,
}` return exactly your desired output?

Comment: To clarify my doubt, please compile your MWE above, without `[\colorCycle]` and `\newcommand{\colorCycle}{%` and `\newcounter{colorCycleCounter}
\preto\addplot{\stepcounter{colorCycleCounter}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{axis}{\setcounter{colorCycleCounter}{0}}` and see the result.

Comment: @C.F.G Unless I'm mistaken, and if I refer to page 425 of the PGFplots manual, the `cycle list/BuGn-5` command is just used to activate the `cycle list` so that it can be reused later in the document. The last activated `cycle list` will be used by default. Thus, in my case, the `color list` `BuGn-9` will be used for graphs containing 1, 2, 3, . . . curves while this `cycle list` should only be used for graphs containing 9 curves.

Comment: Have you compiled the above code as the previous comment?

Comment: I made the compilation as mentioned in your previous comment, and all graphs actually use the `cycle list` `BuGn-9`. However, `BuGn-9` is not optimized for 2,3 or 5-curve graphics (not enough contrast between colors used).

Comment: But it is exactly same as your image?!!

Comment: Why do you twist the question? Just say first that the problem is the colors contrast!!!

Comment: @C.F.G I updated my question to show you the difference I get.

Comment: Well, now the problem is clear. Note that as I said before you can set `\pgfplotsset{` before each `tikzpicture` if you think that this is not so smart, so I can argue that `cycle list name=` or `[\colorCycle]` is also not smart. Isn't?

Comment: @C.F.G When trying to define the `\colorCycle` function, I wanted to have a function that would automatically choose the appropriate `cycle list`. This function is only used once per graph, and if you add or remove curves in the graph, the choice of the `cycle list` is automatically updated at the next compilation. No manual intervention is required except to call up this function. The `\colorCycle` function as defined in my MWE does not work, and I need help to define it correctly.

Comment: If it is possible to make a computer command, used once in the preamble of the document, to choose this "list of `cycle list`" by default for all graphics, it would be just as well.

Comment: See my answer below, and use the second one. You can define a long list of color and refer to it for all plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a chance to use `\numplots` to obtain the number of total plots.

However, the cycle list (seems to be) is processed before `\numplots`.
So we have to compute the color barehanded (without the help of cycle list).

That also means we have to break the `+` part of `\addplot+`,
so the marks are now gone.
Maybe other people know how to add them back.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{colormap/BuGn-9}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\plotnum{0} % emergency default value
\def\numplots{9} % emergency default value
\pgfplotsset{
    color according to numplots/.style={
        every axis plot/.style={
            /utils/exec={
                \pgfmathsetmacro\safenumberofplot{max(\numplots,2)}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\metavalue{1000*(\plotnum+1)/\safenumberofplot}
            },
            color of colormap=\metavalue of BuGn-9,.
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[color according to numplots]
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[color according to numplots]
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(3,0)(4,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(4,0)(5,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[color according to numplots]
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(3,0)(4,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(4,0)(5,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(5,0)(6,1)};
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(6,0)(7,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Resetting `\pgfplotsset{` before each `\begin{tikzpicture}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotsset{
        cycle list/BuGn-3,
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        cycle list/BuGn-3,
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        cycle list/BuGn-5,
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(3,0)(4,1)};
    \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(4,0)(5,1)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2. Defining new color list by `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist` and calling it by `cycle list name=`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{newcycle1}{blue!20\\blue!30\\blue!40\\}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{newcycle2}{blue!20\\blue!60\\blue!90\\}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{newcycle3}{green\\red\\yellow\\purple\\black\\}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[cycle list name=newcycle1]%"cycle list name=BuGn-3"
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[cycle list name=newcycle2]%"cycle list name=BuGn-3"
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[cycle list name=newcycle3]%"cycle list name=BuGn-5"
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(1,0)(2,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(2,0)(3,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(3,0)(4,1)};
        \addplot+[very thick] coordinates {(4,0)(5,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can define a long list of colors like `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{newcycle}{blue!20\\blue!60\\blue!90\\blue!20!green\\blue!60!green\\blue!90!green\\blue!20!red\\blue!60!red\\blue!90!red\\}` and call this `cycle list name=newcycle` in all plots.

[image]

Comment: Having already read the documentation of PGFplots, I know these commands. This does not solve my problem, since you specify manually for each chart which `cycle list` you want to use. For example, if I add two curves (materialized by the `\addplot` commands) to your chart number 2, the `cycle list` will not be changed automatically, I should change it manually (or possibly forget to change it).

Comment: @BLegrand: Please please read the last para. The last image in my answer has been compiled just by one color list. (all 3 figures)

Comment: I’m sorry, but that still doesn’t answer my initial question. I know the commands you use and I use them myself on a regular basis. Whatever the number of curves, the color alternation will always be: `blue!20\\blue!60\\blue!90\. . .`, something I don’t necessarily want. Example: For a graph of two curves, I would like `red` and then `blue`, but for a graph of 3 curves, I would like the alternance `red`, `purple` and then `blue`. In this case, I should create 2 `cycle list` which I should call manually. Back to square one. . .

Comment: Sorry I am complaining, but why you don't tell all of these once in the question?

Comment: Just look at your example that is your desired one. Is that colored by red, blue, ...?

Comment: I thought the title of the question was explicit. It is specified “Automatic selection”. If you think you can improve the wording of my question, feel free to change it. I used examples to illustrate, I also said it.

Comment: You are confused me completely. just  judge yourself: "Here is for example the expected result" + "Example: For a graph of two curves, I would like red and then blue, but for a graph of 3 curves, I would like the alternance `red`, `purple` and then `blue`" + upvote the other answer that is equivalence to my answer and is not  `red`, `purple` and then `blue`.

Comment: I added this image to my question to show you what my MWE should give using an automatic control. i.e. how to choose automatically  a `cycle list` depending on the number of curves. This is a general issue and does not relate to a particular `cycle list`. I only give examples to illustrate what I am saying. The response given by Symbol 1 defines the command `color according to numplots`, which automatically selects the colors based on a color map. Although the answer is not perfect, it does allow the selection of a colour list to be automated and allowed me to learn more technically.

Comment: How Symbol 1 answer is automated? S\He added `[color according to numplots]` to options of `axis` and mine is also have an option in `axis`. So how it is automated?

Comment: Let's imagine that I initially have a graph with 3 curves, so I use the `cycle list` `BuGn-3`. I later add a curve to my graph, so I have to use the `cycle list` `BuGn-4`, except that I'm quite dizzy and forgot to manually change `BuGn-3` to `BuGn-4`. With Symbol 1's solution, there is not this problem, whatever the number of curves in the graph, I have only one option to indicate: `color according to numplots`. That is the whole point of her/his solution.

Comment: Have you compiled my solution? In my solution we have only one option to indicate also (see last paragraph): `cycle list name=newcycle`. So what is the automate there that is not in mine?

Comment: I think what B means is that your solution seems to draw from the same large cycle list, however, B wants items to be drawn from different cycle lists, depending on how many plots are there in totality. Think of it as this way, you offer a long cycle value list (0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,...,1) and draw from that, but what B wants is if you have 2 plots draw from (0, 1), in case of 3 from (0,0.5,1) in case of 4 from (0,0.33,0.66,1) etc. But obviously the color analog of that.